# How to control ajax calls without effecting memory of server?

Tags: plugin-development, ajax, server

I am trying to understand how ajax call and memory of server are linked? Is there any parameter in WordPress control this.

Say if am importing something big using ajax how can perform that without effecting the server with a memory limit of 250MB?

Pls help

Comment: Are you trying to deal with a problem related to this? If so what's the problem

Comment: They’re not linked. An AJAX request is just the browser opening a page in the background, and it will work exactly the same as if you did it yourself. AJAX is not going to get around any process time or memory limits in your server. The limits are the same as any other page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An AJAX request to your server is no different to any other PHP request the server might handle, e.g. the frontend.

Browser requests have a time and memory limit configured at the server level, *WordPress itself is not responsible for setting or enforcing those limits.*

> Say if am importing something big using ajax how can perform that without effecting the server with a memory limit of 250MB?

You have the following options:

1. Use less memory
2. Don't process the entire import in a single request
3. Break your import file into smaller chunks that get processed separately
4. Do the processing elsewhere, e.g. a CLI task. PHP running from a CLI command has no upper limit on time or memory except the amount of physical memory installed on the server.

Otherwise, you can't do stuff for free, there is always a cost. Browser requests are not suited to long running expensive/heavy tasks.

Comment: Thank you. I was actually looking for method to import in small chunks. Are there methods to split big xml to chunks? If possible will you be able to show me reference link to learn that pls.

Comment: I don't have any resources to share, and it's very difficult to advise without knowing the full schema/structure/format of the XML file. You should enquire about this with the people who write the software that generated the XML as simply chopping it into equal parts then fixing any markup errors might break the XML file irreparably